# Regular Expression Results Not as Expected

Tags: javascript, regex

I have the following string:

```
string = 1231231223123131_FILE_NAME.EXTENSION.OTHEREXTENSION
```

and the following regular expression:

```
string.match(/^\d+_([^.]+\.[^.]+)/)[1]
```

the regular expression returns:

```
 => FILE_NAME.EXTENSION
```

While I understand that ^\d+_ is indicating find one of more digits followed by an underscore, my confusion is in the capture group. Particularly why [^.]+ seems to be returning one or more characters before a period and then including the period, but excluding the second period with the second instance of [^.]+

This regular expression combination is even more confusing when you remove the first [^.]+, because then it returns the .OTHEREXTENSION as well.

From my understanding using the caret inside a parentheses [^.] means to exclude whatever follows it. So why in this instance is it including all characters up to and after the first period?

Comment: you've got a `\.` right after it, why wouldn't it include the period?

Comment: wouldn't that mean to exclude all characters before the period though? except it's not. it's returning FILE_NAME

Comment: it's even more confusing when you remove the first [^.]+, because then it returns the .OTHEREXTENSION as well

Comment: Also, what do you want the result to be? `FILE_NAME.EXTENSION.OTHEREXTENSION`?

Comment: the returned result is fine. i'm just confused why it's returning that.

Comment: ".. In most regex flavors, the only special characters or metacharacters inside a character class [ ... ] are the closing bracket ], the backslash \, the caret ^, and the hyphen - "  https://www.regular-expressions.info/charclass.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your capturing group says any character that's not a `.` then a single `.` then another group of non `.` characters.  The `.` in your result is not coming from the first `[^.]+`, it's coming from the `\.` that follows it and is still within the capturing group.

`FILE_NAME.EXTENSION` meets that criteria.  `FILE_NAME` matches the first character class 1 or more times.  This is followed by a dot which matches `\.`  Then the word `EXTENSION` meets the second character class one or more times.  When it reaches the 2nd dot the capturing group comes to an end since the regex contains nothing further to match a second `.`

Comment: no problem.  [regex101.com](https://regex101.com/) is a nice tool that can sometimes be helpful breaking things down when you feel confused.

Comment: thanks i'll start using that. rubular is kind of limiting at times.

Answer (score 2):

In your regex, you have `[^.]+\.[^.]+`

`[^.]+`  stands for *one or more, non-period characters* which matches `FILE_NAME`, and stops when it reaches the period `.`

`\.` matches a single period `.`, which it does (after `FILE_NAME` but before `EXTENSION.OTHEREXTENSION`).

The next `[^.]+` matches *one or more, non-period characters* again, which is `EXTENSION`, and stops again when it reaches the period `.`

Comment: @Dog No worries :)

Comment: i actually think your answer is a lot more clearly worded than mine which reads like a bit of a jumbled mess :- )